# Programmatically create new tab on SAFARI works as new WINDOW instead

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome, safari, firefox4

Using either _newtab or _blank should enable any browser to open a new tab for a given link. I've tried that in a project's site and both works for Firefox 4 and Google chrome but Safari 4.0.3 always opens in a new window.

How can I force safari to open the link in a new tab? Does this issue have something to do with Safari settings...?

ASAP help, thanks very much!

Comment: I've seen IE open _blank in a new window as well, could be a browser settings thing like you said. Check if it happens with IE, if it does then it might just come down to browser implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using mac osx and can't check on IE. I've also seen browser settings for Safari 4.0.3 and changed it's settings "Open links from applications" from option: "in a new window" to "in a new tab in the current window" but the link still opens in new window not in new tab...

Comment: Ok, I found this in the internet: http://www.getbetterat.com/mac-os-x/how-to-force-safari-4-to-open-new-windows-in-tabs/ but still can't make the link open in new tab. I asked my team mate to try it with his safari version 5, and it also doesn't work. We checked HIS safari settings and noticed the open pages/links in new tab was set to Never so we changed it to always, and after that the link works. Sheesh -_-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/243266/jmccarthy:
It's in the safari settings.